# Atmosphere Async Communication (Websockets, long polling) support on android webview with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

I have created simple chat application which is fully based on html, JavaScript and JQuery on the UI side and Spring REST in back-end (DB). here i'm using phone gap to convert my web app into native Android application. lets assume the scenario that, there are the two users in one conversation, the first user sending message to the second user. here i want to update the second user screen using atmosphere asynchronous communication.

but the Android WebView isn't supporting websockets to perform asynchronous communication between the server and the client. how can use atmosphere plugin on the android WebView.
is there any possible ways to do it? please share your answers if you know.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution? please answer your own question.

Comment: I have used socketIO javascript library, if your webview does not support the websocket it'll change to failover mode if you mentioned. here i have mentioned failover mode as long-polling.